# Calling an AWS lambda from a Static WebSite hosted in an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

Currently I have a website that calls a lambda to perform CRUD operations. In AWS the website is hosted in an S3 bucket and the lambda in an EC2 instance. The website locally would refer to something like localhost:8080/parcelUpdate. How would this type of communication occur with an AWS VPC?

Comment: I believe you would want to get the public IP of the EC2 instance...although why would somebody host a Lambda in an EC2 instance?

Comment: What do you mean by " lambda in an EC2 instance"?

Comment: It's not a lambda if it's in an ec2 ... thats a server. Lambdas are "serverless"

Answer (score 1):

An AWS Lambda Function is not hosted on EC2†

You can put a Lambda Function behind an Application Load Balancer or API Gateway, and call it from there

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-alb.html

† Actually, it is deep down, but not YOUR EC2. It's hosted on AWS's own serverless framework in an AWS-managed VPC. It does technically run on an EC2 instance, but that's not something you need to manage

Comment: Apologies it's an ECS Service. Firstly I would like to be able to hit the API myself. I've tried adding my ip address to the inbound rules but it isn't working.